# Show most used apps/programs in Application Overview

Tags: 20.10, dash-to-dock

I have just upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10. The first difference I notice is with the activities screen. I am using Dash to Dock and when I click on the "Show apps/activities" button (three rows of three dots) I get the first of four screens showing all of the apps and programs on my machine listed in alphabetical order.

Previously only the most used apps/programs appeared.

I can alter the behaviour of Dash to Dock, but cannot see how to revert to just showing the apps I most use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has changed in Gnome Shell 3.38, which is used in Ubuntu 20.10. The "Frequent" tab has been removed.

Another change is that applications are not anymore automatically arranged in alphabetical order. You can now order the applications according to your preference, and easily create groups by dragging one application on another, or on an already existing group.

So indeed, the recent Gnome Shell version introduces a different workflow here. You still have the Dash to place your most used applications. On a second level, you can order the icons on the Applications overview to your liking, i.e., you can place your most frequently used ones on the first page yourself.

This change has the benefit of providing a more "stable" application overview: your custom view is stable, as setup by yourself, and applications you install later are in first instance being added at the end. It is normal, of course, that not all users may like this change.

You can at any time "reset" the application overview to an alphabetical order, and with only the default groups by issuing a command using the terminal or the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Run dialog:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout
```